# How to display customized URL through Routeconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an action link in HTML.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("UserWisedPost", "Blog", new { userName = item.UserName,userId=item.UserId })">@item.UserName</a>
```

In controller,

```
public ActionResult UserWisedPost(string userId,string userName, int? page, int pageSize = 10)
{
     page = page == null || page == 0 ? 1 : page;
     var model = _post.GetByUserId(userId).ToPagedList((int)page, pageSize); 
     return View(model);
}
```

And in RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "userwisedPost",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{userName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "UserWisedPost", userName=UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

You have probably understood what I want to mean. I want to display URL like `../UserWisedPost/userName` but want access data by `userId` in controller.

How can I do that?

Comment: So right now you have something like this: `../UserWisedPost/userName?userId=123` right? If so, what's the issue?

Comment: Your controller action should only take the `userName` as input, and then in the action method, you need a way to convert this to a `userId`. Alternatively, you could alter your `_post` to be able to fetch posts by `userName`. But we don't know how your backend is structured, so no one can give an exact answer to your issue.

Comment: I don't want to show userid. But in controller , I want to access data by userid

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that the default route is taking precedence.

I'm guessing you have this before your custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

You need your custom route before this one, otherwise this will be the route that handles requests to your `BlogController`.

A simple way to solve this would be something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "userwisedPost",
            url: "Blog/{action}/{userName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "UserWisedPost", userName = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This would result in a url like this: `Blog/UserWisedPost/SomeUserName?userId=someUserId`

Comment: I don't want to show userid in url. But in controller , I want to access data by userid

Comment: You need to show the userId if you're passing it as a url-parameter.

Comment: The only other way would be to use a form and POST the values. Then they wouldn't show up, but it wouldn't be an anchor, but a form to submit.

Comment: See this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648869/passing-parameters-to-controller-but-not-on-the-url

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the `userId` other than query string you should add a form and put it as a hidden field.

Or, you can use AJAX to post the data:

```
<a href="postUserWised(@Url.Action("UserWisedPost", "Blog"), @item.UserName,@item.UserId)">@item.UserName</a>
```

Then in your scripts section in that view:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
   function postUserWised( url, userName, userId) {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: POST,
        data: { userName: userName, userId: userId },
        success: function(data) { },
        error: function(...) { } 
      });
   }
</script>
}
```

I haven't tested this but it should point you in the right direction.